# Do I need to uninstall Django at root if using virtualenv?

Tags: python, django

I have installed Django into a virtualenv using PIP but I don't have the django-admin.py file. If I drill down into the sub directories:
Directory: C:\virtual\env\is\here\lib\site-packages\

I have these:

```
d----        18/03/2015     12:25            django-1.7.6-py2.7.egg
d----        18/03/2015     10:23            pip
d----        18/03/2015     10:23            pip-1.5.6.dist-inf
d----        18/03/2015     10:22            setuptools
d----        18/03/2015     10:22            setuptools-3.6.dis
d----        18/03/2015     10:22            _markerlib
-a---        18/03/2015     12:28        213 easy-install.pth
-a---        18/03/2015     10:22        126 easy_install.py
-a---        18/03/2015     10:22        361 easy_install.pyc
-a---        18/03/2015     10:22     100868 pkg_resources.py
-a---        18/03/2015     10:22     118464 pkg_resources.pyc
```

The tutorial I am following expects to find the django-admin file so am not sure what to do next.

thanks

Comment: I have never worked on windows environment but pip copies `django-admin.py` in your `/virtual/env/is/here/bin` which is then appended to the PATH variable. Check your virtual env bin folder and append that to your PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You do not need to uninstall django at root if using virtualenv.